# When I run the http://localhost:2222/auth with the Imsomnia, my terminal from VS Code a error:

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

When I try authenticate a user in the Imsomnia, it always loading and my VS Code terminal give me a error

Error from the VS Code terminal

```
(node:6632) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Illegal arguments: undefined, string
    at _async (D:\Progamming\Visual_Studio_Code\Projeto_01\backend\node_modules\bcryptjs\dist\bcrypt.js:286:46)
    at D:\Progamming\Visual_Studio_Code\Projeto_01\backend\node_modules\bcryptjs\dist\bcrypt.js:307:17
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.bcrypt.compare (D:\Progamming\Visual_Studio_Code\Projeto_01\backend\node_modules\bcryptjs\dist\bcrypt.js:306:20)
    at D:\Progamming\Visual_Studio_Code\Projeto_01\backend\src\routes.js:31:21
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:85:5)
(node:6632) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:6632) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

My route.js code:

```js
const express = require('express');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

const User = require('./models/UserModel');

const routes = express.Router();

routes.get('/', (req, res) => {
  return res.send('Hello, World!')
});

routes.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.create(req.body);

    return res.send({ user })
  } catch {
    return res.status(400).send({ error: 'Registration failed' })
  }
});

routes.post('/auth', async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  const user = await User.findOne({ email }).select('+password');

  if (!user){
    return res.status(400).send({ error: 'User not found' });
  };

  if (!await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)){
    return res.status(400).send({ error: 'Invalid password '});
  };

  res.send({ user });
})

module.exports = routes;
```

My UserModel.js:

````
```js
const { Schema, model} = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

const UserSchema = new Schema ({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true,
    lowercase: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    select: false,
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
})

UserSchema.pre('save', async function(next) {
  const hash = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, 10);
  this.password = hash;

  next();
})


module.exports = model('User', UserSchema)
```
````

My server.js code:

```js
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const routes = require('./routes');

const app = express();
const server = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);

mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://admin:mypassword@cluster0-pgqxw.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority', {
  useNewUrlParser: true
});

app.use(express.json());
app.use(routes);

app.listen(2222);
```

It's all my backend code for now

My question is about how can I fix this

Comment: Use try/catch the same way you did for the other promises

Comment: Seems like the error is with the bcrypt. Make sure that password from req.body is not undefined. Also wrap the /auth in the try-catch block.

Comment: This is where "reading the stack trace" matters: the text tells you that there's an uncaught exception, because code was passed "Illegal arguments: undefined, string". It tells you that the first place it's caught in _your_ code is D:\Progamming\Visual_Studio_Code\Projeto_01\backend\src\routes.js:31:21, so what's on that line? And now that you know what's on that line, what would "Illegal arguments: undefined, string" mean? Simply answering those questions by carefully reading is automatically the answer to "what do I do here?".